# Undefined amount of arguments in UML

Tags: uml

I want to make an public method:

```
fun createStringBinding(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String, vararg args: Any): StringBinding {
  return Bindings.createStringBinding(Callable { get(key, *args) }, Settings.language)
}
```

how would this look like in an **UML** i was doing it like that but i am not sure if this is correct and i also don't know where to look for that...
[image]
Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation for operations is described in the UML specifications published by OMG, version 2.5.1, section 9.6.4 and for parameters in section 9.4.4. The latter reads as follows:

`<parameter> ::= [<direction>] <parameter-name> ’:’ <type-expression> [’[’<multiplicity-range>’]’] [’=’ <default>] [’{’ <parm-property> [’,’ <parm-property>]* ’}’]`

The multiplicity must be put behind the parameter type, not behind the name. Your operation would be specified as follows:

`+ createStringBinding(key : String, args : Any[0..*]): StringBinding`

Note, that `Any` and `StringBinding` are not standard UML data types.

UML does not have a standard notation for annotations.