# How to describe an operator method in UML

Tags: uml

I have the following method:

```
operator fun get(key: String): String {
 //awesome code
}
```

I have searched a lot, but I could not find anything which actually helped me understand how to describe the operator in the UML.

i am doing it like that:

```
+ get(in key: String) : String
```

I think the **in** is the right operator in this case right?

The best link I have found so far...:
[www.uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56488387/undefined-amount-of-arguments-in-uml

Comment: @admirallit i dont think thats a duplicate its about the "operator" here?

Comment: I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: No thx for taking your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML does not have a standard way to declare operations to be operators, but you could define your own stereotype for it:

[image]

And then use it like this:

[image: operatoruse]

The keyword `in` is optional. If you don't specify `in`, `out` or `inout`, then the parameter is an input parameter by default. If your operator modifies `key` (I don't know if Kotlin supports that), then you should use keyword `inout`.